# open file for reading with notepad++ in c#

Tags: c#

I try to open file for reading with notepad++, in c# language.
I use this command:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
Process.Start("notepad++.exe", @"c:\file name for test.txt");
```

notepad++ can't open this file with full name,

notepad++  cut the name at 4 part, and return this message

> c:\file doesn't exist.create it?
>
> c:\name doesn't exist.create it?
>
> c:\for doesn't exist.create it?
>
> c:\test.txt doesn't exist.create it?

version of notepad++ : 9.4.2

In the newer version I do not have this problem but I need to use notepad++ with all versions.

Comment: In general, filenames and file systems don't like spaces. Take this into consideration when testing (and also naming files)

Comment: Please add double quotes to the 2nd parameter! Like this: `Process.Start("notepad++.exe", "\"" + @"c:\file name for test.txt" + "\"");`

Answer (score 13):

You are missing the quotes around the filename.

Try this:

```
Process myProcess = new Process(); 
Process.Start("notepad++.exe", "\"c:\\file name for test.txt\"");
```

Comment: @abdosup I tried this on my PC and it works OK. The first time I run it, Notepad++ asks if I want to create the file. I say yes, then save the file. The next time I run it, it just opens the file. What happens when you try it?

Comment: try to use notepad++ 4.9.2 ,  because i need to open existing file with this version, maybe you have the newer version. thank you

Comment: Why you have Process myProcess = new Process(); ?

Comment: @Teomanshipahi Well, it's a direct copy from the OP, that's why. ;)

Comment: @MatthewWatson and I copied from your answer, and Resharper told me, remove dat line :) Thanks!